# Split a table and send the Hex key

Tags: lua

I am tryin to convert a table I have with a limit of 16 characters to hex keys and then store those hex keys in another table in the same order as the original string.

I have found a function using some online help which can take a string, split it into each character and assign that character to a space in a table.

So if I write function("Hello World!")
the return of the function would be table= {H, e, l, l, o, , W, o, r, l, d, !)

Now I need to limit this to only accept 16 characters and any more than that are discarded.

The function goes as

```
local str = "Hello World"
local chars = {}

for c in string.gmatch(str, ".") do
chars[#chars+1] = c
end
```

How can I limit this to 16 elements in the table?

My second question would be after I create this table, how do I go about changing each element of this table to a hex key and storing it in another table in the same order as the original string?

EDIT1: Thank you luke10000 for suggesting the if char.. method, it works perfectly. Now the next part is to convert this to hex and place it in a table.
I found a function which does this operation but there was no explanation with it at all, I understand some of it but not all. I can only print with this to the console all the hex keys.

```
   function hex_dump(buf)
  for byte=1, #buf, 16 do
     local chunk = buf:sub(byte, byte+15)
     --io.write(string.format('%08X  ',byte-1)) -- 0's
     chunk:gsub('.', function (c) io.write(string.format('0x%X ',string.byte(c))) end)
     io.write(string.rep(' ',3*(16-#chunk)),"\n")
     --io.write(' ',chunk:gsub('%c','.'),"\n")  -- add the character infront of hex key
  end end

for _, chars in ipairs(chars) do


hex_dump(chars) end
```

Comment: Just subtract 32, that is space `' '` from each character. Will work for the standard ASCII characters at least. It is very trivial to do in C, I have no idea how you'd do the same in Lua.

Comment: `if #chars == 16 then break end` would be a quick fix for problem one. Alternatively, you can directly write `for i = 1, math.min(#str, 16) do chars[i] = str:sub(i, i) end` or something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the rest of your post is related to your actual problem.

> I am tryin to convert a table I have with a limit of 16 characters to
> hex keys and then store those hex keys in another table in the same
> order as the original string.

I'm also not sure what you mean with "hex key".

```
local input = {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d", "!"}
local output = {}    
for i,v in ipairs(input) do
  output[i] = string.format("0x%X", v:byte())
  if i == 16 then break end
end
print(table.concat(output, ", "))
```

Regarding your other questions:

> ```
> local str = "Hello World"
> local chars = {}
>
> for c in string.gmatch(str, ".") do
> chars[#chars+1] = c
> end
> ```
>
> How can I limit this to 16 elements in the table?

Simply limit your input string to 16 characters.

`for c in str:sub(1,16):gmatch(".") do` ...

> My second question would be after I create this table, how do I go
> about changing each element of this table to a hex key and storing it
> in another table in the same order as the original string?

If your actual problem is to get a table of number representations from a string, simply use `string.byte`

```
local str = "Hello world! This is a wonderful day.!"
local output = table.pack(str:byte(1, 16))
```